# ubuntu 14.04 overheating problem

Tags: 14.04, overheating

i am new with ubuntu so i need some help.
i installed 14.04 but laptop keeps overheating all the time. searched around the net, but could not find solution.
can anyone help?
i have HP Probook 4525s.

Comment: open System monitor then open its Processes tab, click on CPU column(to sort it in decending order) so that it can show which application is eating the most CPU

Comment: If there is not a process using a high CPU, clean your machine and vents

Comment: hey edward, thanks for fast reply. did as you told me, gnome-system-monitor is on first place with CPU usage. average usage is  15-20. what should i do?

Comment: hey bodhi, i did that already. laptop was totally clean inside.

Answer (score 1):

here i am back again. So after going back to windows, trying openSUSE, eOS... i have found out that the problem in my case is AMD/ATI driver.
I have installed eOS 0.3 (ubuntu 14.04 based) and by default it have chosen the X.Org AMD/ATI driver but the pc temperature was again around 82 degrees C. So i went to additional drivers and picked AMD fglrx proprietary.
Now I am happy to say that my linux is running smoothly and cpu/gpu temperature does not exceed 61 degrees C. Hope this will help! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by installing compizconfig-settings-manager (CCSM).

> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Then open it up by searching in dash.
then search for OpenGL. click on it.
Now you see "Texture Filter" set it to "Fast"
now uncheck the "Sync to Vblank"
Done

Comment: tried this one yesterday with a big help from edward, but sadly everything is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can install TLP, a power management tool. TLP comes with a default configuration already optimized for battery life and reduces overheating.

You can install TLP with the following commands

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install tlp`

After installation, start TLP using the command

`sudo tlp start`

This command is required only once.

Comment: hey rohith, tried this also, but still CPU is very hot and fan keep running almost constantly. thanks anyways.

Comment: just installing this software wont help, you have to configure it also. which you should read first from official website